# Rendering or deleting emoji

Tags: javascript, twitter, unicode, emoji

I'm pulling tweets from Twitter and want to show them on a web page, but instead of emoji I only see boxes for characters like  and .  How can I show these as images like Twitter, or if that's not possible, strip them all out?

I tried:

```
item["text"] = item["text"].replace('', "");
```

but it is throwing js error.

Comment: you should get its unicode code.

Comment: You have a lone `"`.  Maybe you meant `''` instead?  BTW, strings are immutable in JavaScript, so `replace()` *returns* the new string.

Comment: you don't need to get rid of anything.  these are perfectly valid characters, and they render fine for me, because i have appropriate fonts installed: http://i.imgur.com/ZnKsMIS.png

Comment: @Eevee building on your response, the OP can import the proper font to their website in order for it to render

Comment: Also might want to take a look at your text encoding. You might not have a program that's expecting these characters. As mentioned above, though, watch that " vs '', and you want item["text"] = item["text"].replace('blah','');.

Comment: yes, and symbola is such a font, available [here](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/).  you can also do what twitter does and replace all the characters with `<img>` tags, but you'd need an icon set.  (i suppose you could just borrow twitter's.)  also keep in mind that javascript strings are terrible and not actually unicode — they're encoded UTF-16, in which emoji are _two_ "characters".

Comment: assuming you like my answer, do you mind if i edit your question so it's easier for others to find?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please, please, **never blindly delete chunks of text**, especially not just because you can't see or understand them; it destroys information.  Someone put them there for a reason; tweets containing emoji often don't make any sense without the emoji.

For what it's worth, what you're seeing isn't really "binary"; it's most likely a small square with the Unicode codepoint spelled out in hex.  For , that's U+1F49C, so you probably see `0 1 F` `4 9 C`.  This is how Unicode characters are rendered when none of your installed fonts have glyphs for them.

To actually see the characters, you have several options.

1. Get Symbola from [here](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/), and install it.  Now you can see emoji.  But no one else can.
2. Get Symbola, and add it to your website with a `@font-face` block like this:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: Symbola;
       src: url('Symbola.ttf') format('truetype');
       unicode-range: U+1F???;
   }
   ```

   Then set your page's font with `font-family: Symbola, "your preferred font", sans-serif;`.

   The downside to this is that, to my understanding, CSS's `font-family` picks the first font that exists at all, and does *not* specify a Unicode fallback.  So in browsers that don't support `unicode-range` ([Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=unicode-range)), that will render your *entire page* in the not particularly beautiful Symbola.

   You could sorta hack around this by finding all the emoji and wrapping them in a `<span class="emoji">`, then only using Symbola for `.emoji` elements.
3. Find all the emoji and replace them with `<img>` tags, like Twitter does.  Twitter's images are all at URLs containing the codepoint, e.g. https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/1f43e.png, so just reusing those is easy enough.  (I'm a little surprised the Twitter API won't do this for you, actually.)

If you want to find and replace all emoji, you probably want to just look for all astral-plane characters — i.e., those not in the Basic Multilingual Plane where modern human languages live.  These are all characters with codepoints of U+10000 and above.

In JavaScript, strings aren't really strings; they're arrays of 16-bit numbers.  16 bits is four hex digits, so Unicode codepoints that have five hex digits won't fit in a single 16-bit number.  Instead, JavaScript encodes them with the terrible UTF-16 encoding, which uses two 16-bit numbers: one in the range 0xD800 to 0xDBFF and one in the range 0xDC00 to 0xDFFF.  Two numbers together are called a "surrogate pair".  None of these numbers will ever be real Unicode codepoints; the entire block is reserved for this encoding.

To find all the astral plane characters, you actually want to find all the surrogate pairs:

```
/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/
```

So an implementation of Twitter's image replacement might look like this:

```
var text = "hey babe    how you doin";

// Split on surrogate pairs, and preserve the surrogates; this will give
// you an array that alternates between BMP text and a single surrogate
// pair: [text, emoji, text, emoji, text...]
var chunks = text.split(/([\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF])/);

// A DocumentFragment is a DOM tree that can be manipulated freely without
// causing a reflow, so it's more performant for heavy tree-building and a
// good habit to get into
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0, l = chunks.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        // Even-numbered chunks are plain text
        frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chunks[i]));
    }
    else {
        // Odd-numbered chunks are surrogate pairs
        // We have TWO characters, but we want one codepoint; this is how
        // you decode UTF-16  :(
        var pair = chunks[i];
        var codepoint = (
            0x10000
            | ((pair.charCodeAt(0) - 0xD800) << 10)
            | (pair.charCodeAt(1) - 0xDC00)
        );
        var hex = codepoint.toString(16);  // now it's in hex
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/" + hex + ".png";
        // Twitter uses pretty big images and just scales them down
        // clientside; you could change these to whatever you want, or add
        // a class here and use CSS to set the width/height to 1em to
        // match the current font size
        img.height = 16;
        img.width = 16;
        frag.appendChild(img);
    }
}

// Now just stick it into the page somewhere
var el = document.createElement('p');
el.appendChild(frag);
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

This creates an `<img>` as per option 3, but you could also easily add a `<span class="emoji">` and go with option 2.  Or do whatever else you want, like replace emoji with their Unicode names.  (Twitter has the Unicode names as `title` on each image, but that's not done here because it requires including a huge list mapping codepoints to names  ☺)

Comment: This code snippet is exactly what I was looking for! I made a jQuery plugin from it.

Comment: This was a very good answer, thanks for providing it. I added a  full implementation of #3 than handles a few more cases.

Comment: Default settings for JSLint and other quality checkers don't accept several of the Twitter Flags and Sequences. See below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26899821/791932

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what is or is not a Twitter Emoji is not simply all code points >= U+10000. There is also the issue of the [regional flags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol), and the [variant sequences](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/StandardizedVariants.html).

I realized this is probably going to be a common problem so until the Twitter API provides native Emoji support, you can try something similar to this:

```
// This represents all of the Emoji Twitter supports as of August 2014. The order is important for the flags
// which are formed by combining two smaller Emoji. The codes at the end have optional standard variants that
// need to be treated as a contiguous span when present.
//
// This is written as a string rather than a raw regex, because js compressors do a good job concatenating
// and converting unicode escape characters into binary for strings, but not regexes.
var EMOJI_REGEX = new RegExp(
    "\ud83c\uddec\ud83c\udde7|\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8|\ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea|\ud83c\uddea\ud83c\uddf8|" +
    "\ud83c\uddeb\ud83c\uddf7|\ud83c\udde8\ud83c\uddf3|\ud83c\uddee\ud83c\uddf9|\ud83c\uddef\ud83c\uddf5|" +
    "\ud83c\uddf0\ud83c\uddf7|\ud83c\uddf7\ud83c\uddfa|\ud83d\udc7a|\ud83c\udd94|\ud83c\udd95|\ud83c\udd96|" +
    "\ud83c\udd97|\ud83c\udd98|\ud83c\udd99|\ud83c\udd9a|\ud83c\udde6|\ud83c\udde7|\ud83d\udc83|\ud83c\udde8|" +
    "\ud83c\udccf|\ud83c\udde9|\ud83c\udd70|\ud83c\uddea|\ud83c\udd71|\ud83c\uddeb|\ud83c\udd7e|\ud83c\uddec|" +
    "\ud83c\udded|\ud83c\uddee|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c\uddef|\ud83c\udd91|\ud83c\uddf0|\ud83c\uddf1|\ud83c\uddf2|" +
    "\ud83c\uddf3|\ud83c\uddf4|\ud83c\uddf5|\ud83c\uddf6|\ud83c\udd92|\ud83c\uddf7|\ud83c\uddf8|\ud83c\uddf9|" +
    "\ud83c\udd93|\ud83c\uddfa|\ud83c\uddfb|\ud83c\uddfc|\ud83c\uddfd|\ud83c\uddfe|\ud83c\uddff|\ud83c\ude01|" +
    "\ud83c\ude02|\ud83c\ude32|\ud83c\ude33|\ud83c\ude34|\ud83c\ude35|\ud83c\ude36|\ud83c\ude37|\ud83c\ude38|" +
    "\ud83c\ude39|\ud83c\ude3a|\ud83c\ude50|\ud83c\ude51|\ud83c\udf00|\ud83c\udf01|\ud83c\udf02|\ud83c\udf03|" +
    "\ud83c\udf04|\ud83c\udf05|\ud83c\udf06|\ud83c\udf07|\ud83c\udf08|\ud83c\udf09|\ud83c\udf0a|\ud83c\udf0b|" +
    "\ud83c\udf0c|\ud83c\udf0d|\ud83c\udf0e|\ud83c\udf0f|\ud83c\udf10|\ud83c\udf11|\ud83c\udf12|\ud83c\udf13|" +
    "\ud83c\udf14|\ud83c\udf15|\ud83c\udf16|\ud83c\udf17|\ud83c\udf18|\ud83c\udf19|\ud83c\udf1a|\ud83c\udf1b|" +
    "\ud83c\udf1c|\ud83c\udf1d|\ud83c\udf1e|\ud83c\udf1f|\ud83c\udf20|\ud83c\udf30|\ud83c\udf31|\ud83c\udf32|" +
    "\ud83c\udf33|\ud83c\udf34|\ud83c\udf35|\ud83c\udf37|\ud83c\udf38|\ud83c\udf39|\ud83c\udf3a|\ud83c\udf3b|" +
    "\ud83c\udf3c|\ud83c\udf3d|\ud83c\udf3e|\ud83c\udf3f|\ud83c\udf40|\ud83c\udf41|\ud83c\udf42|\ud83c\udf43|" +
    "\ud83c\udf44|\ud83c\udf45|\ud83c\udf46|\ud83c\udf47|\ud83c\udf48|\ud83c\udf49|\ud83c\udf4a|\ud83c\udf4b|" +
    "\ud83c\udf4c|\ud83c\udf4d|\ud83c\udf4e|\ud83c\udf4f|\ud83c\udf50|\ud83c\udf51|\ud83c\udf52|\ud83c\udf53|" +
    "\ud83c\udf54|\ud83c\udf55|\ud83c\udf56|\ud83c\udf57|\ud83c\udf58|\ud83c\udf59|\ud83c\udf5a|\ud83c\udf5b|" +
    "\ud83c\udf5c|\ud83c\udf5d|\ud83c\udf5e|\ud83c\udf5f|\ud83c\udf60|\ud83c\udf61|\ud83c\udf62|\ud83c\udf63|" +
    "\ud83c\udf64|\ud83c\udf65|\ud83c\udf66|\ud83c\udf67|\ud83c\udf68|\ud83c\udf69|\ud83c\udf6a|\ud83c\udf6b|" +
    "\ud83c\udf6c|\ud83c\udf6d|\ud83c\udf6e|\ud83c\udf6f|\ud83c\udf70|\ud83c\udf71|\ud83c\udf72|\ud83c\udf73|" +
    "\ud83c\udf74|\ud83c\udf75|\ud83c\udf76|\ud83c\udf77|\ud83c\udf78|\ud83c\udf79|\ud83c\udf7a|\ud83c\udf7b|" +
    "\ud83c\udf7c|\ud83c\udf80|\ud83c\udf81|\ud83c\udf82|\ud83c\udf83|\ud83c\udf84|\ud83c\udf85|\ud83c\udf86|" +
    "\ud83c\udf87|\ud83c\udf88|\ud83c\udf89|\ud83c\udf8a|\ud83c\udf8b|\ud83c\udf8c|\ud83c\udf8d|\ud83c\udf8e|" +
    "\ud83c\udf8f|\ud83c\udf90|\ud83c\udf91|\ud83c\udf92|\ud83c\udf93|\ud83c\udfa0|\ud83c\udfa1|\ud83c\udfa2|" +
    "\ud83c\udfa3|\ud83c\udfa4|\ud83c\udfa5|\ud83c\udfa6|\ud83c\udfa7|\ud83c\udfa8|\ud83c\udfa9|\ud83c\udfaa|" +
    "\ud83c\udfab|\ud83c\udfac|\ud83c\udfad|\ud83c\udfae|\ud83c\udfaf|\ud83c\udfb0|\ud83c\udfb1|\ud83c\udfb2|" +
    "\ud83c\udfb3|\ud83c\udfb4|\ud83c\udfb5|\ud83c\udfb6|\ud83c\udfb7|\ud83c\udfb8|\ud83c\udfb9|\ud83c\udfba|" +
    "\ud83c\udfbb|\ud83c\udfbc|\ud83c\udfbd|\ud83c\udfbe|\ud83c\udfbf|\ud83c\udfc0|\ud83c\udfc1|\ud83c\udfc2|" +
    "\ud83c\udfc3|\ud83c\udfc4|\ud83c\udfc6|\ud83c\udfc7|\ud83c\udfc8|\ud83c\udfc9|\ud83c\udfca|\ud83c\udfe0|" +
    "\ud83c\udfe1|\ud83c\udfe2|\ud83c\udfe3|\ud83c\udfe4|\ud83c\udfe5|\ud83c\udfe6|\ud83c\udfe7|\ud83c\udfe8|" +
    "\ud83c\udfe9|\ud83c\udfea|\ud83c\udfeb|\ud83c\udfec|\ud83c\udfed|\ud83c\udfee|\ud83c\udfef|\ud83c\udff0|" +
    "\ud83d\udc00|\ud83d\udc01|\ud83d\udc02|\ud83d\udc03|\ud83d\udc04|\ud83d\udc05|\ud83d\udc06|\ud83d\udc07|" +
    "\ud83d\udc08|\ud83d\udc09|\ud83d\udc0a|\ud83d\udc0b|\ud83d\udc0c|\ud83d\udc0d|\ud83d\udc0e|\ud83d\udc0f|" +
    "\ud83d\udc10|\ud83d\udc11|\ud83d\udc12|\ud83d\udc13|\ud83d\udc14|\ud83d\udc15|\ud83d\udc16|\ud83d\udc17|" +
    "\ud83d\udc18|\ud83d\udc19|\ud83d\udc1a|\ud83d\udc1b|\ud83d\udc1c|\ud83d\udc1d|\ud83d\udc1e|\ud83d\udc1f|" +
    "\ud83d\udc20|\ud83d\udc21|\ud83d\udc22|\ud83d\udc23|\ud83d\udc24|\ud83d\udc25|\ud83d\udc26|\ud83d\udc27|" +
    "\ud83d\udc28|\ud83d\udc29|\ud83d\udc2a|\ud83d\udc2b|\ud83d\udc2c|\ud83d\udc2d|\ud83d\udc2e|\ud83d\udc2f|" +
    "\ud83d\udc30|\ud83d\udc31|\ud83d\udc32|\ud83d\udc33|\ud83d\udc34|\ud83d\udc35|\ud83d\udc36|\ud83d\udc37|" +
    "\ud83d\udc38|\ud83d\udc39|\ud83d\udc3a|\ud83d\udc3b|\ud83d\udc3c|\ud83d\udc3d|\ud83d\udc3e|\ud83d\udc40|" +
    "\ud83d\udc42|\ud83d\udc43|\ud83d\udc44|\ud83d\udc45|\ud83d\udc46|\ud83d\udc47|\ud83d\udc48|\ud83d\udc49|" +
    "\ud83d\udc4a|\ud83d\udc4b|\ud83d\udc4c|\ud83d\udc4d|\ud83d\udc4e|\ud83d\udc4f|\ud83d\udc50|\ud83d\udc51|" +
    "\ud83d\udc52|\ud83d\udc53|\ud83d\udc54|\ud83d\udc55|\ud83d\udc56|\ud83d\udc57|\ud83d\udc58|\ud83d\udc59|" +
    "\ud83d\udc5a|\ud83d\udc5b|\ud83d\udc5c|\ud83d\udc5d|\ud83d\udc5e|\ud83d\udc5f|\ud83d\udc60|\ud83d\udc61|" +
    "\ud83d\udc62|\ud83d\udc63|\ud83d\udc64|\ud83d\udc65|\ud83d\udc66|\ud83d\udc67|\ud83d\udc68|\ud83d\udc69|" +
    "\ud83d\udc6a|\ud83d\udc6b|\ud83d\udc6c|\ud83d\udc6d|\ud83d\udc6e|\ud83d\udc6f|\ud83d\udc70|\ud83d\udc71|" +
    "\ud83d\udc72|\ud83d\udc73|\ud83d\udc74|\ud83d\udc75|\ud83d\udc76|\ud83d\udc77|\ud83d\udc78|\ud83d\udc79|" +
    "\ud83d\udc7b|\ud83d\udc7c|\ud83d\udc7d|\ud83d\udc7e|\ud83d\udc7f|\ud83d\udc80|\ud83d\udc81|\ud83d\udc82|" +
    "\ud83d\udc84|\ud83d\udc85|\ud83d\udc86|\ud83d\udc87|\ud83d\udc88|\ud83d\udc89|\ud83d\udc8a|\ud83d\udc8b|" +
    "\ud83d\udc8c|\ud83d\udc8d|\ud83d\udc8e|\ud83d\udc8f|\ud83d\udc90|\ud83d\udc91|\ud83d\udc92|\ud83d\udc93|" +
    "\ud83d\udc94|\ud83d\udc95|\ud83d\udc96|\ud83d\udc97|\ud83d\udc98|\ud83d\udc99|\ud83d\udc9a|\ud83d\udc9b|" +
    "\ud83d\udc9c|\ud83d\udc9d|\ud83d\udc9e|\ud83d\udc9f|\ud83d\udca0|\ud83d\udca1|\ud83d\udca2|\ud83d\udca3|" +
    "\ud83d\udca4|\ud83d\udca5|\ud83d\udca6|\ud83d\udca7|\ud83d\udca8|\ud83d\udca9|\ud83d\udcaa|\ud83d\udcab|" +
    "\ud83d\udcac|\ud83d\udcad|\ud83d\udcae|\ud83d\udcaf|\ud83d\udcb0|\ud83d\udcb1|\ud83d\udcb2|\ud83d\udcb3|" +
    "\ud83d\udcb4|\ud83d\udcb5|\ud83d\udcb6|\ud83d\udcb7|\ud83d\udcb8|\ud83d\udcb9|\ud83d\udcba|\ud83d\udcbb|" +
    "\ud83d\udcbc|\ud83d\udcbd|\ud83d\udcbe|\ud83d\udcbf|\ud83d\udcc0|\ud83d\udcc1|\ud83d\udcc2|\ud83d\udcc3|" +
    "\ud83d\udcc4|\ud83d\udcc5|\ud83d\udcc6|\ud83d\udcc7|\ud83d\udcc8|\ud83d\udcc9|\ud83d\udcca|\ud83d\udccb|" +
    "\ud83d\udccc|\ud83d\udccd|\ud83d\udcce|\ud83d\udccf|\ud83d\udcd0|\ud83d\udcd1|\ud83d\udcd2|\ud83d\udcd3|" +
    "\ud83d\udcd4|\ud83d\udcd5|\ud83d\udcd6|\ud83d\udcd7|\ud83d\udcd8|\ud83d\udcd9|\ud83d\udcda|\ud83d\udcdb|" +
    "\ud83d\udcdc|\ud83d\udcdd|\ud83d\udcde|\ud83d\udcdf|\ud83d\udce0|\ud83d\udce1|\ud83d\udce2|\ud83d\udce3|" +
    "\ud83d\udce4|\ud83d\udce5|\ud83d\udce6|\ud83d\udce7|\ud83d\udce8|\ud83d\udce9|\ud83d\udcea|\ud83d\udceb|" +
    "\ud83d\udcec|\ud83d\udced|\ud83d\udcee|\ud83d\udcef|\ud83d\udcf0|\ud83d\udcf1|\ud83d\udcf2|\ud83d\udcf3|" +
    "\ud83d\udcf4|\ud83d\udcf5|\ud83d\udcf6|\ud83d\udcf7|\ud83d\udcf9|\ud83d\udcfa|\ud83d\udcfb|\ud83d\udcfc|" +
    "\ud83d\udd00|\ud83d\udd01|\ud83d\udd02|\ud83d\udd03|\ud83d\udd04|\ud83d\udd05|\ud83d\udd06|\ud83d\udd07|" +
    "\ud83d\udd08|\ud83d\udd09|\ud83d\udd0a|\ud83d\udd0b|\ud83d\udd0c|\ud83d\udd0d|\ud83d\udd0e|\ud83d\udd0f|" +
    "\ud83d\udd10|\ud83d\udd11|\ud83d\udd12|\ud83d\udd13|\ud83d\udd14|\ud83d\udd15|\ud83d\udd16|\ud83d\udd17|" +
    "\ud83d\udd18|\ud83d\udd19|\ud83d\udd1a|\ud83d\udd1b|\ud83d\udd1c|\ud83d\udd1d|\ud83d\udd1e|\ud83d\udd1f|" +
    "\ud83d\udd20|\ud83d\udd21|\ud83d\udd22|\ud83d\udd23|\ud83d\udd24|\ud83d\udd25|\ud83d\udd26|\ud83d\udd27|" +
    "\ud83d\udd28|\ud83d\udd29|\ud83d\udd2a|\ud83d\udd2b|\ud83d\udd2c|\ud83d\udd2d|\ud83d\udd2e|\ud83d\udd2f|" +
    "\ud83d\udd30|\ud83d\udd31|\ud83d\udd32|\ud83d\udd33|\ud83d\udd34|\ud83d\udd35|\ud83d\udd36|\ud83d\udd37|" +
    "\ud83d\udd38|\ud83d\udd39|\ud83d\udd3a|\ud83d\udd3b|\ud83d\udd3c|\ud83d\udd3d|\ud83d\udd50|\ud83d\udd51|" +
    "\ud83d\udd52|\ud83d\udd53|\ud83d\udd54|\ud83d\udd55|\ud83d\udd56|\ud83d\udd57|\ud83d\udd58|\ud83d\udd59|" +
    "\ud83d\udd5a|\ud83d\udd5b|\ud83d\udd5c|\ud83d\udd5d|\ud83d\udd5e|\ud83d\udd5f|\ud83d\udd60|\ud83d\udd61|" +
    "\ud83d\udd62|\ud83d\udd63|\ud83d\udd64|\ud83d\udd65|\ud83d\udd66|\ud83d\udd67|\ud83d\uddfb|\ud83d\uddfc|" +
    "\ud83d\uddfd|\ud83d\uddfe|\ud83d\uddff|\ud83d\ude00|\ud83d\ude01|\ud83d\ude02|\ud83d\ude03|\ud83d\ude04|" +
    "\ud83d\ude05|\ud83d\ude06|\ud83d\ude07|\ud83d\ude08|\ud83d\ude09|\ud83d\ude0a|\ud83d\ude0b|\ud83d\ude0c|" +
    "\ud83d\ude0d|\ud83d\ude0e|\ud83d\ude0f|\ud83d\ude10|\ud83d\ude11|\ud83d\ude12|\ud83d\ude13|\ud83d\ude14|" +
    "\ud83d\ude15|\ud83d\ude16|\ud83d\ude17|\ud83d\ude18|\ud83d\ude19|\ud83d\ude1a|\ud83d\ude1b|\ud83d\ude1c|" +
    "\ud83d\ude1d|\ud83d\ude1e|\ud83d\ude1f|\ud83d\ude20|\ud83d\ude21|\ud83d\ude22|\ud83d\ude23|\ud83d\ude24|" +
    "\ud83d\ude25|\ud83d\ude26|\ud83d\ude27|\ud83d\ude28|\ud83d\ude29|\ud83d\ude2a|\ud83d\ude2b|\ud83d\ude2c|" +
    "\ud83d\ude2d|\ud83d\ude2e|\ud83d\ude2f|\ud83d\ude30|\ud83d\ude31|\ud83d\ude32|\ud83d\ude33|\ud83d\ude34|" +
    "\ud83d\ude35|\ud83d\ude36|\ud83d\ude37|\ud83d\ude38|\ud83d\ude39|\ud83d\ude3a|\ud83d\ude3b|\ud83d\ude3c|" +
    "\ud83d\ude3d|\ud83d\ude3e|\ud83d\ude3f|\ud83d\ude40|\ud83d\ude45|\ud83d\ude46|\ud83d\ude47|\ud83d\ude48|" +
    "\ud83d\ude49|\ud83d\ude4a|\ud83d\ude4b|\ud83d\ude4c|\ud83d\ude4d|\ud83d\ude4e|\ud83d\ude4f|\ud83d\ude80|" +
    "\ud83d\ude81|\ud83d\ude82|\ud83d\ude83|\ud83d\ude84|\ud83d\ude85|\ud83d\ude86|\ud83d\ude87|\ud83d\ude88|" +
    "\ud83d\ude89|\ud83d\ude8a|\ud83d\ude8b|\ud83d\ude8c|\ud83d\ude8d|\ud83d\ude8e|\ud83d\ude8f|\ud83d\ude90|" +
    "\ud83d\ude91|\ud83d\ude92|\ud83d\ude93|\ud83d\ude94|\ud83d\ude95|\ud83d\ude96|\ud83d\ude97|\ud83d\ude98|" +
    "\ud83d\ude99|\ud83d\ude9a|\ud83d\ude9b|\ud83d\ude9c|\ud83d\ude9d|\ud83d\ude9e|\ud83d\ude9f|\ud83d\udea0|" +
    "\ud83d\udea1|\ud83d\udea2|\ud83d\udea3|\ud83d\udea4|\ud83d\udea5|\ud83d\udea6|\ud83d\udea7|\ud83d\udea8|" +
    "\ud83d\udea9|\ud83d\udeaa|\ud83d\udeab|\ud83d\udeac|\ud83d\udead|\ud83d\udeae|\ud83d\udeaf|\ud83d\udeb0|" +
    "\ud83d\udeb1|\ud83d\udeb2|\ud83d\udeb3|\ud83d\udeb4|\ud83d\udeb5|\ud83d\udeb6|\ud83d\udeb7|\ud83d\udeb8|" +
    "\ud83d\udeb9|\ud83d\udeba|\ud83d\udebb|\ud83d\udebc|\ud83d\udebd|\ud83d\udebe|\ud83d\udebf|\ud83d\udec0|" +
    "\ud83d\udec1|\ud83d\udec2|\ud83d\udec3|\ud83d\udec4|\ud83d\udec5|\u0023\u20e3|\u0030\u20e3|\u0031\u20e3|" +
    "\u0032\u20e3|\u0033\u20e3|\u0034\u20e3|\u0035\u20e3|\u0036\u20e3|\u0037\u20e3|\u0038\u20e3|\u0039\u20e3|" +
    "\u3030|\u2705|\u2728|\u2122|\u23e9|\u23ea|\u23eb|\u23ec|\u23f0|\u23f3|\u26ce|\u270a|\u270b|\u274c|\u274e|" +
    "\u27b0|\u27bf|\u2753|\u2754|\u2755|\u2795|\u2796|\u2797|\u00a9|\u00ae|\ue50a|" +
    "(\ud83c\udd7f|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c\udc04|\u2935|\u3297|\u3299|\u2049|\u2139|\u2194|\u2195|" +
    "\u2196|\u2197|\u2198|\u2199|\u2600|\u2601|\u2611|\u2614|\u2615|\u2648|\u2649|\u2650|\u2651|\u2652|\u2653|" +
    "\u2660|\u2663|\u2665|\u2666|\u2668|\u2693|\u2702|\u2708|\u2709|\u2712|\u2714|\u2716|\u2733|\u2734|\u203c|" +
    "\u21a9|\u21aa|\u2744|\u231a|\u231b|\u24c2|\u25aa|\u25ab|\u25b6|\u25c0|\u25fb|\u25fc|\u25fd|\u25fe|\u260e|" +
    "\u261d|\u263a|\u264a|\u264b|\u264c|\u264d|\u264e|\u264f|\u267b|\u267f|\u26a0|\u26a1|\u26aa|\u26ab|\u26bd|" +
    "\u26be|\u26c4|\u26c5|\u26d4|\u26ea|\u26f2|\u26f3|\u26f5|\u26fa|\u26fd|\u270c|\u270f|\u27a1|\u2b05|\u2b06|" +
    "\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u2747|\u303d|\u2757|\u2764|\u2934)([\ufe0e\ufe0f]?)", "g");

// Example:
document.body.innerHTML = renderEmoji("Hello \ud83d\ude1c!");

// For safety, Emoji should only be converted in the plain text spans of Tweets, not a fully linkified Tweet.

function renderEmoji(text) {
  return text.replace(EMOJI_REGEX, function(baseAndVariant, base, variant) {
    if (variant == "\ufe0e") {
      // Do not emojify this variant.
      return baseAndVariant;
    }

    // Convert UTF-16 into a sequence of hex codes
    base = base || baseAndVariant;
    var codes = [];
    base.replace(/([\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])|./g, function(any, nonBmp) {
      var code = nonBmp ?
          ((nonBmp.charCodeAt(0) & 0x3ff) << 10) + (nonBmp.charCodeAt(1) & 0x3ff) + 0x10000 : 
          any.charCodeAt(0);
      codes.push(code.toString(16));
    });

    var src = "//abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/" + codes.join('-') + ".png";

    // The inline images depends on this css being in the head somehere:
    // .twitter-emoji {
    //   height: 1em;
    //   width: 1em;
    //   padding: 0 0.05em 0 0.1em;
    //   vertical-align: -0.1em;
    // }
    // The alt attribute gets used when users copy and paste an img into a plain text editor.
    return '<img src=' + src + ' class="twitter-emoji" alt="' + baseAndVariant + '">';
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

twitter finally released it ;)
Hope it helps
https://github.com/twitter/twemoji

Answer (score 0):

Default settings for JSLint and other quality checkers don't accept several of the Twitter Flags and Sequences.

For convenience, based on the answer above, I've commented out the offending escape sequences and used the actual characters in the Regex.

```
EMOJI_REGEX: new RegExp(
    '\ud83c\uddec\ud83c\udde7|\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8|\ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea|\ud83c\uddea\ud83c\uddf8|' +
    '\ud83c\uddeb\ud83c\uddf7|\ud83c\udde8\ud83c\uddf3|\ud83c\uddee\ud83c\uddf9|\ud83c\uddef\ud83c\uddf5|' +
    '\ud83c\uddf0\ud83c\uddf7|\ud83c\uddf7\ud83c\uddfa|\ud83d\udc7a|\ud83c\udd94|\ud83c\udd95|\ud83c\udd96|' +
    '\ud83c\udd97|\ud83c\udd98|\ud83c\udd99|\ud83c\udd9a|\ud83c\udde6|\ud83c\udde7|\ud83d\udc83|\ud83c\udde8|' +
    '\ud83c\udccf|\ud83c\udde9|\ud83c\udd70|\ud83c\uddea|\ud83c\udd71|\ud83c\uddeb|\ud83c\udd7e|\ud83c\uddec|' +
    '\ud83c\udded|\ud83c\uddee|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c\uddef|\ud83c\udd91|\ud83c\uddf0|\ud83c\uddf1|\ud83c\uddf2|' +
    '\ud83c\uddf3|\ud83c\uddf4|\ud83c\uddf5|\ud83c\uddf6|\ud83c\udd92|\ud83c\uddf7|\ud83c\uddf8|\ud83c\uddf9|' +
    '\ud83c\udd93|\ud83c\uddfa|\ud83c\uddfb|\ud83c\uddfc|\ud83c\uddfd|\ud83c\uddfe|\ud83c\uddff|\ud83c\ude01|' +
    '\ud83c\ude02|\ud83c\ude32|\ud83c\ude33|\ud83c\ude34|\ud83c\ude35|\ud83c\ude36|\ud83c\ude37|\ud83c\ude38|' +
    '\ud83c\ude39|\ud83c\ude3a|\ud83c\ude50|\ud83c\ude51|\ud83c\udf00|\ud83c\udf01|\ud83c\udf02|\ud83c\udf03|' +
    '\ud83c\udf04|\ud83c\udf05|\ud83c\udf06|\ud83c\udf07|\ud83c\udf08|\ud83c\udf09|\ud83c\udf0a|\ud83c\udf0b|' +
    '\ud83c\udf0c|\ud83c\udf0d|\ud83c\udf0e|\ud83c\udf0f|\ud83c\udf10|\ud83c\udf11|\ud83c\udf12|\ud83c\udf13|' +
    '\ud83c\udf14|\ud83c\udf15|\ud83c\udf16|\ud83c\udf17|\ud83c\udf18|\ud83c\udf19|\ud83c\udf1a|\ud83c\udf1b|' +
    '\ud83c\udf1c|\ud83c\udf1d|\ud83c\udf1e|\ud83c\udf1f|\ud83c\udf20|\ud83c\udf30|\ud83c\udf31|\ud83c\udf32|' +
    '\ud83c\udf33|\ud83c\udf34|\ud83c\udf35|\ud83c\udf37|\ud83c\udf38|\ud83c\udf39|\ud83c\udf3a|\ud83c\udf3b|' +
    '\ud83c\udf3c|\ud83c\udf3d|\ud83c\udf3e|\ud83c\udf3f|\ud83c\udf40|\ud83c\udf41|\ud83c\udf42|\ud83c\udf43|' +
    '\ud83c\udf44|\ud83c\udf45|\ud83c\udf46|\ud83c\udf47|\ud83c\udf48|\ud83c\udf49|\ud83c\udf4a|\ud83c\udf4b|' +
    '\ud83c\udf4c|\ud83c\udf4d|\ud83c\udf4e|\ud83c\udf4f|\ud83c\udf50|\ud83c\udf51|\ud83c\udf52|\ud83c\udf53|' +
    '\ud83c\udf54|\ud83c\udf55|\ud83c\udf56|\ud83c\udf57|\ud83c\udf58|\ud83c\udf59|\ud83c\udf5a|\ud83c\udf5b|' +
    '\ud83c\udf5c|\ud83c\udf5d|\ud83c\udf5e|\ud83c\udf5f|\ud83c\udf60|\ud83c\udf61|\ud83c\udf62|\ud83c\udf63|' +
    '\ud83c\udf64|\ud83c\udf65|\ud83c\udf66|\ud83c\udf67|\ud83c\udf68|\ud83c\udf69|\ud83c\udf6a|\ud83c\udf6b|' +
    '\ud83c\udf6c|\ud83c\udf6d|\ud83c\udf6e|\ud83c\udf6f|\ud83c\udf70|\ud83c\udf71|\ud83c\udf72|\ud83c\udf73|' +
    '\ud83c\udf74|\ud83c\udf75|\ud83c\udf76|\ud83c\udf77|\ud83c\udf78|\ud83c\udf79|\ud83c\udf7a|\ud83c\udf7b|' +
    '\ud83c\udf7c|\ud83c\udf80|\ud83c\udf81|\ud83c\udf82|\ud83c\udf83|\ud83c\udf84|\ud83c\udf85|\ud83c\udf86|' +
    '\ud83c\udf87|\ud83c\udf88|\ud83c\udf89|\ud83c\udf8a|\ud83c\udf8b|\ud83c\udf8c|\ud83c\udf8d|\ud83c\udf8e|' +
    '\ud83c\udf8f|\ud83c\udf90|\ud83c\udf91|\ud83c\udf92|\ud83c\udf93|\ud83c\udfa0|\ud83c\udfa1|\ud83c\udfa2|' +
    '\ud83c\udfa3|\ud83c\udfa4|\ud83c\udfa5|\ud83c\udfa6|\ud83c\udfa7|\ud83c\udfa8|\ud83c\udfa9|\ud83c\udfaa|' +
    '\ud83c\udfab|\ud83c\udfac|\ud83c\udfad|\ud83c\udfae|\ud83c\udfaf|\ud83c\udfb0|\ud83c\udfb1|\ud83c\udfb2|' +
    '\ud83c\udfb3|\ud83c\udfb4|\ud83c\udfb5|\ud83c\udfb6|\ud83c\udfb7|\ud83c\udfb8|\ud83c\udfb9|\ud83c\udfba|' +
    '\ud83c\udfbb|\ud83c\udfbc|\ud83c\udfbd|\ud83c\udfbe|\ud83c\udfbf|\ud83c\udfc0|\ud83c\udfc1|\ud83c\udfc2|' +
    '\ud83c\udfc3|\ud83c\udfc4|\ud83c\udfc6|\ud83c\udfc7|\ud83c\udfc8|\ud83c\udfc9|\ud83c\udfca|\ud83c\udfe0|' +
    '\ud83c\udfe1|\ud83c\udfe2|\ud83c\udfe3|\ud83c\udfe4|\ud83c\udfe5|\ud83c\udfe6|\ud83c\udfe7|\ud83c\udfe8|' +
    '\ud83c\udfe9|\ud83c\udfea|\ud83c\udfeb|\ud83c\udfec|\ud83c\udfed|\ud83c\udfee|\ud83c\udfef|\ud83c\udff0|' +
    '\ud83d\udc00|\ud83d\udc01|\ud83d\udc02|\ud83d\udc03|\ud83d\udc04|\ud83d\udc05|\ud83d\udc06|\ud83d\udc07|' +
    '\ud83d\udc08|\ud83d\udc09|\ud83d\udc0a|\ud83d\udc0b|\ud83d\udc0c|\ud83d\udc0d|\ud83d\udc0e|\ud83d\udc0f|' +
    '\ud83d\udc10|\ud83d\udc11|\ud83d\udc12|\ud83d\udc13|\ud83d\udc14|\ud83d\udc15|\ud83d\udc16|\ud83d\udc17|' +
    '\ud83d\udc18|\ud83d\udc19|\ud83d\udc1a|\ud83d\udc1b|\ud83d\udc1c|\ud83d\udc1d|\ud83d\udc1e|\ud83d\udc1f|' +
    '\ud83d\udc20|\ud83d\udc21|\ud83d\udc22|\ud83d\udc23|\ud83d\udc24|\ud83d\udc25|\ud83d\udc26|\ud83d\udc27|' +
    '\ud83d\udc28|\ud83d\udc29|\ud83d\udc2a|\ud83d\udc2b|\ud83d\udc2c|\ud83d\udc2d|\ud83d\udc2e|\ud83d\udc2f|' +
    '\ud83d\udc30|\ud83d\udc31|\ud83d\udc32|\ud83d\udc33|\ud83d\udc34|\ud83d\udc35|\ud83d\udc36|\ud83d\udc37|' +
    '\ud83d\udc38|\ud83d\udc39|\ud83d\udc3a|\ud83d\udc3b|\ud83d\udc3c|\ud83d\udc3d|\ud83d\udc3e|\ud83d\udc40|' +
    '\ud83d\udc42|\ud83d\udc43|\ud83d\udc44|\ud83d\udc45|\ud83d\udc46|\ud83d\udc47|\ud83d\udc48|\ud83d\udc49|' +
    '\ud83d\udc4a|\ud83d\udc4b|\ud83d\udc4c|\ud83d\udc4d|\ud83d\udc4e|\ud83d\udc4f|\ud83d\udc50|\ud83d\udc51|' +
    '\ud83d\udc52|\ud83d\udc53|\ud83d\udc54|\ud83d\udc55|\ud83d\udc56|\ud83d\udc57|\ud83d\udc58|\ud83d\udc59|' +
    '\ud83d\udc5a|\ud83d\udc5b|\ud83d\udc5c|\ud83d\udc5d|\ud83d\udc5e|\ud83d\udc5f|\ud83d\udc60|\ud83d\udc61|' +
    '\ud83d\udc62|\ud83d\udc63|\ud83d\udc64|\ud83d\udc65|\ud83d\udc66|\ud83d\udc67|\ud83d\udc68|\ud83d\udc69|' +
    '\ud83d\udc6a|\ud83d\udc6b|\ud83d\udc6c|\ud83d\udc6d|\ud83d\udc6e|\ud83d\udc6f|\ud83d\udc70|\ud83d\udc71|' +
    '\ud83d\udc72|\ud83d\udc73|\ud83d\udc74|\ud83d\udc75|\ud83d\udc76|\ud83d\udc77|\ud83d\udc78|\ud83d\udc79|' +
    '\ud83d\udc7b|\ud83d\udc7c|\ud83d\udc7d|\ud83d\udc7e|\ud83d\udc7f|\ud83d\udc80|\ud83d\udc81|\ud83d\udc82|' +
    '\ud83d\udc84|\ud83d\udc85|\ud83d\udc86|\ud83d\udc87|\ud83d\udc88|\ud83d\udc89|\ud83d\udc8a|\ud83d\udc8b|' +
    '\ud83d\udc8c|\ud83d\udc8d|\ud83d\udc8e|\ud83d\udc8f|\ud83d\udc90|\ud83d\udc91|\ud83d\udc92|\ud83d\udc93|' +
    '\ud83d\udc94|\ud83d\udc95|\ud83d\udc96|\ud83d\udc97|\ud83d\udc98|\ud83d\udc99|\ud83d\udc9a|\ud83d\udc9b|' +
    '\ud83d\udc9c|\ud83d\udc9d|\ud83d\udc9e|\ud83d\udc9f|\ud83d\udca0|\ud83d\udca1|\ud83d\udca2|\ud83d\udca3|' +
    '\ud83d\udca4|\ud83d\udca5|\ud83d\udca6|\ud83d\udca7|\ud83d\udca8|\ud83d\udca9|\ud83d\udcaa|\ud83d\udcab|' +
    '\ud83d\udcac|\ud83d\udcad|\ud83d\udcae|\ud83d\udcaf|\ud83d\udcb0|\ud83d\udcb1|\ud83d\udcb2|\ud83d\udcb3|' +
    '\ud83d\udcb4|\ud83d\udcb5|\ud83d\udcb6|\ud83d\udcb7|\ud83d\udcb8|\ud83d\udcb9|\ud83d\udcba|\ud83d\udcbb|' +
    '\ud83d\udcbc|\ud83d\udcbd|\ud83d\udcbe|\ud83d\udcbf|\ud83d\udcc0|\ud83d\udcc1|\ud83d\udcc2|\ud83d\udcc3|' +
    '\ud83d\udcc4|\ud83d\udcc5|\ud83d\udcc6|\ud83d\udcc7|\ud83d\udcc8|\ud83d\udcc9|\ud83d\udcca|\ud83d\udccb|' +
    '\ud83d\udccc|\ud83d\udccd|\ud83d\udcce|\ud83d\udccf|\ud83d\udcd0|\ud83d\udcd1|\ud83d\udcd2|\ud83d\udcd3|' +
    '\ud83d\udcd4|\ud83d\udcd5|\ud83d\udcd6|\ud83d\udcd7|\ud83d\udcd8|\ud83d\udcd9|\ud83d\udcda|\ud83d\udcdb|' +
    '\ud83d\udcdc|\ud83d\udcdd|\ud83d\udcde|\ud83d\udcdf|\ud83d\udce0|\ud83d\udce1|\ud83d\udce2|\ud83d\udce3|' +
    '\ud83d\udce4|\ud83d\udce5|\ud83d\udce6|\ud83d\udce7|\ud83d\udce8|\ud83d\udce9|\ud83d\udcea|\ud83d\udceb|' +
    '\ud83d\udcec|\ud83d\udced|\ud83d\udcee|\ud83d\udcef|\ud83d\udcf0|\ud83d\udcf1|\ud83d\udcf2|\ud83d\udcf3|' +
    '\ud83d\udcf4|\ud83d\udcf5|\ud83d\udcf6|\ud83d\udcf7|\ud83d\udcf9|\ud83d\udcfa|\ud83d\udcfb|\ud83d\udcfc|' +
    '\ud83d\udd00|\ud83d\udd01|\ud83d\udd02|\ud83d\udd03|\ud83d\udd04|\ud83d\udd05|\ud83d\udd06|\ud83d\udd07|' +
    '\ud83d\udd08|\ud83d\udd09|\ud83d\udd0a|\ud83d\udd0b|\ud83d\udd0c|\ud83d\udd0d|\ud83d\udd0e|\ud83d\udd0f|' +
    '\ud83d\udd10|\ud83d\udd11|\ud83d\udd12|\ud83d\udd13|\ud83d\udd14|\ud83d\udd15|\ud83d\udd16|\ud83d\udd17|' +
    '\ud83d\udd18|\ud83d\udd19|\ud83d\udd1a|\ud83d\udd1b|\ud83d\udd1c|\ud83d\udd1d|\ud83d\udd1e|\ud83d\udd1f|' +
    '\ud83d\udd20|\ud83d\udd21|\ud83d\udd22|\ud83d\udd23|\ud83d\udd24|\ud83d\udd25|\ud83d\udd26|\ud83d\udd27|' +
    '\ud83d\udd28|\ud83d\udd29|\ud83d\udd2a|\ud83d\udd2b|\ud83d\udd2c|\ud83d\udd2d|\ud83d\udd2e|\ud83d\udd2f|' +
    '\ud83d\udd30|\ud83d\udd31|\ud83d\udd32|\ud83d\udd33|\ud83d\udd34|\ud83d\udd35|\ud83d\udd36|\ud83d\udd37|' +
    '\ud83d\udd38|\ud83d\udd39|\ud83d\udd3a|\ud83d\udd3b|\ud83d\udd3c|\ud83d\udd3d|\ud83d\udd50|\ud83d\udd51|' +
    '\ud83d\udd52|\ud83d\udd53|\ud83d\udd54|\ud83d\udd55|\ud83d\udd56|\ud83d\udd57|\ud83d\udd58|\ud83d\udd59|' +
    '\ud83d\udd5a|\ud83d\udd5b|\ud83d\udd5c|\ud83d\udd5d|\ud83d\udd5e|\ud83d\udd5f|\ud83d\udd60|\ud83d\udd61|' +
    '\ud83d\udd62|\ud83d\udd63|\ud83d\udd64|\ud83d\udd65|\ud83d\udd66|\ud83d\udd67|\ud83d\uddfb|\ud83d\uddfc|' +
    '\ud83d\uddfd|\ud83d\uddfe|\ud83d\uddff|\ud83d\ude00|\ud83d\ude01|\ud83d\ude02|\ud83d\ude03|\ud83d\ude04|' +
    '\ud83d\ude05|\ud83d\ude06|\ud83d\ude07|\ud83d\ude08|\ud83d\ude09|\ud83d\ude0a|\ud83d\ude0b|\ud83d\ude0c|' +
    '\ud83d\ude0d|\ud83d\ude0e|\ud83d\ude0f|\ud83d\ude10|\ud83d\ude11|\ud83d\ude12|\ud83d\ude13|\ud83d\ude14|' +
    '\ud83d\ude15|\ud83d\ude16|\ud83d\ude17|\ud83d\ude18|\ud83d\ude19|\ud83d\ude1a|\ud83d\ude1b|\ud83d\ude1c|' +
    '\ud83d\ude1d|\ud83d\ude1e|\ud83d\ude1f|\ud83d\ude20|\ud83d\ude21|\ud83d\ude22|\ud83d\ude23|\ud83d\ude24|' +
    '\ud83d\ude25|\ud83d\ude26|\ud83d\ude27|\ud83d\ude28|\ud83d\ude29|\ud83d\ude2a|\ud83d\ude2b|\ud83d\ude2c|' +
    '\ud83d\ude2d|\ud83d\ude2e|\ud83d\ude2f|\ud83d\ude30|\ud83d\ude31|\ud83d\ude32|\ud83d\ude33|\ud83d\ude34|' +
    '\ud83d\ude35|\ud83d\ude36|\ud83d\ude37|\ud83d\ude38|\ud83d\ude39|\ud83d\ude3a|\ud83d\ude3b|\ud83d\ude3c|' +
    '\ud83d\ude3d|\ud83d\ude3e|\ud83d\ude3f|\ud83d\ude40|\ud83d\ude45|\ud83d\ude46|\ud83d\ude47|\ud83d\ude48|' +
    '\ud83d\ude49|\ud83d\ude4a|\ud83d\ude4b|\ud83d\ude4c|\ud83d\ude4d|\ud83d\ude4e|\ud83d\ude4f|\ud83d\ude80|' +
    '\ud83d\ude81|\ud83d\ude82|\ud83d\ude83|\ud83d\ude84|\ud83d\ude85|\ud83d\ude86|\ud83d\ude87|\ud83d\ude88|' +
    '\ud83d\ude89|\ud83d\ude8a|\ud83d\ude8b|\ud83d\ude8c|\ud83d\ude8d|\ud83d\ude8e|\ud83d\ude8f|\ud83d\ude90|' +
    '\ud83d\ude91|\ud83d\ude92|\ud83d\ude93|\ud83d\ude94|\ud83d\ude95|\ud83d\ude96|\ud83d\ude97|\ud83d\ude98|' +
    '\ud83d\ude99|\ud83d\ude9a|\ud83d\ude9b|\ud83d\ude9c|\ud83d\ude9d|\ud83d\ude9e|\ud83d\ude9f|\ud83d\udea0|' +
    '\ud83d\udea1|\ud83d\udea2|\ud83d\udea3|\ud83d\udea4|\ud83d\udea5|\ud83d\udea6|\ud83d\udea7|\ud83d\udea8|' +
    '\ud83d\udea9|\ud83d\udeaa|\ud83d\udeab|\ud83d\udeac|\ud83d\udead|\ud83d\udeae|\ud83d\udeaf|\ud83d\udeb0|' +
    '\ud83d\udeb1|\ud83d\udeb2|\ud83d\udeb3|\ud83d\udeb4|\ud83d\udeb5|\ud83d\udeb6|\ud83d\udeb7|\ud83d\udeb8|' +
    '\ud83d\udeb9|\ud83d\udeba|\ud83d\udebb|\ud83d\udebc|\ud83d\udebd|\ud83d\udebe|\ud83d\udebf|\ud83d\udec0|' +
    '\ud83d\udec1|\ud83d\udec2|\ud83d\udec3|\ud83d\udec4|\ud83d\udec5|' +

    // JSLint did not accept these as legitimate escape sequences
    // '\u0023\u20e3|\u0030\u20e3|\u0031\u20e3|' +
    // '\u0032\u20e3|\u0033\u20e3|\u0034\u20e3|\u0035\u20e3|\u0036\u20e3|\u0037\u20e3|\u0038\u20e3|\u0039\u20e3|' +
    // '\u3030|\u2705|\u2728|\u2122|\u23e9|\u23ea|\u23eb|\u23ec|\u23f0|\u23f3|\u26ce|\u270a|\u270b|\u274c|\u274e|' +
    // '\u27b0|\u27bf|\u2753|\u2754|\u2755|\u2795|\u2796|\u2797|\u00a9|\u00ae|\ue50a|' +
    // '(\ud83c\udd7f|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c\udc04|\u2935|\u3297|\u3299|\u2049|\u2139|\u2194|\u2195|' +
    // '\u2196|\u2197|\u2198|\u2199|\u2600|\u2601|\u2611|\u2614|\u2615|\u2648|\u2649|\u2650|\u2651|\u2652|\u2653|' +
    // '\u2660|\u2663|\u2665|\u2666|\u2668|\u2693|\u2702|\u2708|\u2709|\u2712|\u2714|\u2716|\u2733|\u2734|\u203c|' +
    // '\u21a9|\u21aa|\u2744|\u231a|\u231b|\u24c2|\u25aa|\u25ab|\u25b6|\u25c0|\u25fb|\u25fc|\u25fd|\u25fe|\u260e|' +
    // '\u261d|\u263a|\u264a|\u264b|\u264c|\u264d|\u264e|\u264f|\u267b|\u267f|\u26a0|\u26a1|\u26aa|\u26ab|\u26bd|' +
    // '\u26be|\u26c4|\u26c5|\u26d4|\u26ea|\u26f2|\u26f3|\u26f5|\u26fa|\u26fd|\u270c|\u270f|\u27a1|\u2b05|\u2b06|' +
    // '\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u2747|\u303d|\u2757|\u2764|\u2934)([\ufe0e\ufe0f]?)', 'g'),

    '#⃣|0⃣|1⃣|' +
    '2⃣|3⃣|4⃣|5⃣|6⃣|7⃣|8⃣|9⃣|' +
    '〰|✅|✨|™|⏩|⏪|⏫|⏬|⏰|⏳|⛎|✊|✋|❌|❎|' +
    '➰|➿|❓|❔|❕|➕|➖|➗|©|®||' +
    '(||||⤵|㊗|㊙|⁉|ℹ|↔|↕|' +
    '↖|↗|↘|↙|☀|☁|☑|☔|☕|♈|♉|♐|♑|♒|♓|' +
    '♠|♣|♥|♦|♨|⚓|✂|✈|✉|✒|✔|✖|✳|✴|‼|' +
    '↩|↪|❄|⌚|⌛|Ⓜ|▪|▫|▶|◀|◻|◼|◽|◾|☎|' +
    '⚾|⛄|⛅|⛔|⛪|⛲|⛳|⛵|⛺|⛽|✌|✏|➡|⬅|⬆|' +
    '⬇|⬛|⬜|⭐|⭕|❇|〽|❗|❤|⤴)([︎️]?)', 'g');
```