# Parsing characters of strings that include emojis

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer, utf-8

I need to iterate over the characters of a string that may include emojis such as:

`var s = "";`

In javascript, each of these characters contain two code-points. The value of s.length will be 4. But I want to treat them as single characters.   The new "for of" loop (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) does what I want.

```js
var s = "";
alert( "length of " + s + " is " + s.length );
alert( s + " has " + numCharacters( s ) + " characters");

function numCharacters( s ) {
   var count = 0;
   for ( var ch of s ) {
        count++;
   }
   return count ;
}
```

However, it is not supported in IE.  Any suggestions on how to iterate through the characters of a string that may contain emojis which would also work using Internet Explorer?

Comment: have a look here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Comment: Thanks.   That's the information I needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531751/how-can-i-split-a-string-containing-emoji-into-an-array