# In javascript,Can I store emojis in an array as array's element?

Tags: javascript, frontend, web-frontend

I want to store emojis in an array and print it using console.out(); on the browser's console ?

Comment: `var a = [''];  console.info(a[0]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split a string containing emoji into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531751/how-can-i-split-a-string-containing-emoji-into-an-array)

Comment: @Thilo.  I have saved the above code in a js file and then running it, on the console i am getting this garbage value ---  ðŸ™€. please explain.

Comment: Is that JS file properly recognized as UTF-8? You can paste the code into the console in your browser and it works (at least for me).

Answer (score 4):

They're just characters so you can use Unicode escapes. [Just find the one you want](http://emojipedia.org) and use \u plus the codepoint value: \u{xxxxx} where xxxxx is the codepoint. [The syntax with the curly braces only works in ES6](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode). You can only use four hex digits with the original \uxxxx format so if you're stuck pre-ES6 you have to use "surrogate pairs," which is explained in the linked article.

```
var a = [ '\u{1F984}' ];
console.log(a[0]);
```

Running this in Node:

```
$ node
> var a = [ '\u{1F984}' ];
undefined
> console.log(a[0]);

undefined
```

You should see a Unicorn--a white horse with a horn.

If you don't see a Unicorn then maybe you're using a terminal that doesn't support Unicode. I'm using the macOS terminal. Try it in your browser JavaScript console.

Comment: Sir.I have saved the above code in a js file and then running it, on the console i am getting this garbage value "  " not any emojis.

Comment: You should see the Unicorn emoji. If you want a different emoji, change 1F984 to something else. See the linked page for the complete list.