# Generating user initials if the name or surname starts with an emojis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji

In my React application there's the following function which generates the user initials from the first name/last name like so:

```
@computed public get initials() {
  const firstNameLetter = this.firstName
    ? this.firstName[0].toLocaleUpperCase()
    : '';
  const lastNameLetter = this.lastName
    ? this.lastName[0].toLocaleUpperCase()
    : '';

  return `${firstNameLetter}${lastNameLetter}`;
}
```

This works fine. But if the first name or the last name starts with an emoji, this code is basically breaking that emoji and what is displayed is just a question mark. The problem is with taking the first char which is not enough if it's an emoji and it is eventually breaking it.

Is anybody aware of any way of detecting that the first element is an emoji and treat it correspondingly? Or maybe there's a better way of creating the initials other than this kind of split which will deal with emojis as well?

Comment: This doesn't only break with emoji's but with all multi-byte characters. [That's because most languages treat text as bytes instead of characters / codepoints](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: you can use [...this.firstName][0]

Comment: Alternative: strip non-letter-y characters out and take it from there. What if I have TWO emojis? Chaos.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Define "non-letter-y" characters. What about ◌̈ or 思 or ﷽? cycero should first sit down and think about what "initials" mean in non-latin languages (if applicable at all that is).

Comment: @RobIII “non-letter-y” means just that. Pictographic languages don’t have letters; “initials” are non-sensical. There’s no **generic** approach since languages (and/or language groups) have their own conventions. In the context of **this question**, the one we’re answering/commenting on, it looks like the OP is addressing a specific use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split a string containing emoji into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531751/how-can-i-split-a-string-containing-emoji-into-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an easy fix would be to create an array using spread and then get the first element

```js
const firstName = 'ey'
console.log(firstName[0])

//split doesnt work
const firstNameArrSplit = firstName.split("")
console.log(firstNameArrSplit)

const firstNameArrSpread = [...firstName]
console.log(firstNameArrSpread)
console.log(firstNameArrSpread[0])
```

```js
@computed public get initials() {
  const firstNameLetter = this.firstName
    ? [...this.firstName][0].toLocaleUpperCase()
    : '';
  const lastNameLetter = this.lastName
    ? [...this.lastName][0].toLocaleUpperCase()
    : '';

  return `${firstNameLetter}${lastNameLetter}`;
}
```

**edit**
didn't realize that there can be so many edge cases as 0stone0 mentioned in the comments. For a more sophisticated splitting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531751/how-can-i-split-a-string-containing-emoji-into-an-array) has better answers

Comment: Keep in mind that this will break multi-width emoji's: `'‍‍‍ey'`

Comment: @0stone0 oof i didn't realize that

Answer (score 1):

Why we can't use array.from method here instead of split

```js
const firstName = 'ey';

const res = Array.from(firstName);


console.log(res);
```