# android regex for utf-16 emoji

Tags: android, regex, unicode, utf-16, emoji

For example, a emoji  is represented in utf-16 as \ud83d\udc4d

Another emoji ✌ is represented in utf-16 as \u270c

Now, suppose I have a string like:
Hello \ud83d\udc4d bye \u270c

Then how can I have a regex that finds these utf-16 strings?

Because the first result should include \ud83d\udc4d and second result should include \u270c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the regex to extract all the emojis from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840667/what-is-the-regex-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-a-string)