# How To Translate Unicode Value To Emoji String in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert emoji's like the one below to c# code so I can put the code in a TreeView node or facebook or other social engine. I tried the code for airplane and shows a little airplane in the treenode. But I use another airplace code like U+1F6E9 it just shows a little rectangle not the emoji. Please help.

```
string tnt = "Airplane " + char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse("U+2708".Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));

MyTreeView.Nodes.Add(tnt);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Unexpected results? You need to be specific .

Comment: This might work. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950241/10470443)

Comment: First of all, [`U+1F347`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F347) is the Unicode for a grape emoji. The golf one is [`U+26F3`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+26F3). Second, your code outputs the target emoji just fine. What exactly is the problem? Please note that "doesn't work" isn't a good description of a problem.

Comment: What I mean, I need to use code to add an emoji icon to say a Treeview tree node or Facebook post using code derived from the unicode values shown on http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f6b4 in the Code column.

Comment: @GRF I tested your code and both emojis were [displayed in the TreeView](https://i.imgur.com/ejSnrh6.png).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class you may use to implement different emoji's in your application.

```
public class Emoji
{
    readonly int[] codes;
    public Emoji(int[] codes)
    {
        this.codes = codes;
    }

    public Emoji(int code)
    {
        codes = new int[] { code };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (codes == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var sb = new StringBuilder(codes.Length);

        foreach (var code in codes)
            sb.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(code));

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I would use the codes from this site [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f6b4)
Instead of using the code it has on the site which is something like 'U+1F366' I would use '0x1F366' to specify hexadecimal notation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Using those codes from Unicode.org. How could I use your class to say add an emoji image to a Treeview node or a Facebook post?

Comment: This is no different than code provided in the question.  Please clarify how this code solves "so I can put the code in a TreeView node or facebook or other social engine. I tried the code below but doesn't work. "

Comment: Nick, I tried the class above and put the airplane emoji as the image in a treeview node. But if use another airplane code, there is just a little square where the icon should be. Please advise

`Emoji emoji = new Emoji(0x2708); // shows ✈`
`string em = emoji.ToString();`
`EmojiTreeView.Nodes.Add(em);`

`Emoji emoji = new Emoji(0x1F6E9); // shows a tiny triangle`
`em = emoji.ToString();`
`EmojiTreeView.Nodes.Add(em);`