# How to make EditText only allow emoji input?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, emoji

I want my EditText to just accept emojis as an input type. I am using Kotlin, how could I make this work?

Comment: @YaMiN how to do with with regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840667/what-is-the-regex-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-a-string